# jquery function does not work on IE7

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery slider function that works on all browser except IE7. What can be the problem?

This is my function:

```
$(function () {
    $("#slider").responsiveSlides({
        auto: true,
        pager: false,
        nav: true,
        speed: 500,
        namespace: "callbacks",
    });
});
```

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? Did you read the console searching for errors?

Comment: Nobody support IE7. Not even microsoft.

Comment: @SubirKumarSao it is still used by some tired institutions...

Comment: I use jquery 1.9.0. There is one error, but I don get it honestly. SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number 
scripts.js, line 8 character 5

Comment: Post any error if you are getting.

Comment: @name that's great and what code is `line 8` ???

Comment: yeah.. 
`1.$(function () {
2.    $("#slider").responsiveSlides({
3.        auto: true,
4.        pager: false,
5.        nav: true,
6.        speed: 500,
7.        namespace: "callbacks",
8.    });
9.});`

Comment: so my line 8 is:   });

Answer (score 4):

problem is you have an extra `,` trailing  commas in javascript which is creating error in ie 7 ..(i am thinking this is not working in ie6 too)).. remove that and it should work

```
  $("#slider").responsiveSlides({
    auto: true,
    pager: false,
    nav: true,
    speed: 500,
    namespace: "callbacks",
                  //------^-----here..remove this
});
```

Comment: I think its typo and this would give error in other browsers too.

Comment: nopes!!! latest version of chrome and firefox doesn't.. while older version of ie does.. :)

Comment: no.. this is not the problem I guess.. it does not work again

Comment: please recheck.. and make sure you have no other trailing commas in your script.... check if you are getting any errors in developer tool console..

Comment: yeah, I gte such an error: _SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number scripts.js, line 8 character 5_... and line 8 is `)};`

Comment: so it is something else that is breaking the code..... does this line points to above mentioned code ??

Comment: but you already have $(function().. there.. ?? i don't think documnet.ready is the problem

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing the whole code I would say that the problem is that extra , at the end, it should be

```
namespace: "callbacks"
```

I believe that newer versions of IE and other browsers ignore this syntax error but IE7 and earlier don't

Comment: @name it might be best to add your code into a fiddle so we can see how it runs, the , shouldn't be there but there may be some other problem as well.